# How many options can I add in a picklist datatype?

Tags: force.com

I am a newbie to salesforce so it might be a very basic question but really I am keen to know the answer of following questions -

1) How many options can I add in a picklist datatype?

2) Can I add dynamic options to picklist datatype field?

Comment: for now you cannot add the options dynamically.

Comment: You mean to say that i can't load picklist options from any existing data Object. right

Comment: yes you cannot upload the things dynamically but if you really want then you can do using meta data api

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation at http://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/picklist_limitations.htm, the maximum number of values is determined by the total number of characters.  You can have up to 15,000 characters as part of your picklists.

In regards to dynamic options, can you clarify?  Is this like a dependent picklist field where the values available are defined by another field?

Comment: I mean to say can i load picklist options from any existing Object?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 limits when you consider a picklist.
1st is the no. of values i.e 1000 values
2nd is the character limit which is 15000 and is the hard limit.
This 15k also includes return carriage and line breaks

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot directly load options from one field into another field. You would need to enter them manually.

But you restrict the options based on a selection of controlling picklist.
http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm